# Subspaces and elements of isomorphic vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In general, I was wondering what is it that I can say about elements and subspaces of same dimension of isomorphic vector spaces. For instance, if $V$ and $V'$ are isomorphic vector spaces, then can I say that for two subspaces $U \subseteq V$ and $U' \subseteq V'$ of the same dimension, are $U \cong U'$? Also, for any two elements $u \in V$ and $u' \in V'$, can I say something similar of these elements? Namely that $u \cong u'$? Does that even make sense or can I only say that we can find an isomorphism that sends $u$ to $u'$? Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: First: yes, exactly. Second: Does not make sense. But yes, you will find an isomorphism sending $u$ to $u'$ (except when one of them is zero and the other is not).

Comment: What does the congruent symbol mean here?

Comment: It's supposed to mean the spaces $U$ and $U'$ are isomorphic. Same for $u$ and $u'$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp So then the subspaces $U$ and $U'$ are isomorphic and I can find an isomorphism sending $u$ to $u'$, right? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: @user110320 Twice yes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!